# Cannot remove event in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, platform-bug

Error shown that event is used in two applications but it is not really used.

Actually the event was used in component which was used in three applications.

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Salesforce Lightning has some inner table for storing dependencies.

So, if App1, App2 and App3 uses component Comp1 which used Event1, then they have some table like

```
App1 uses Event1
App2 uses Event1
App3 uses Event1
```

When you update Comp1 and App1, it removes App1 from this table but doesn't remove App2 and App3.

```
App1 doesn't use Event1
App2 uses Event1
App3 uses Event1
```

To make it remove we need to make dummy fake save on App2 and App3 so it would update its inner table

```
App1 doesn't use Event1
App2 doesn't use Event1
App3 doesn't use Event1
```

Comment: Same applies for components: have to update them to lose the bogus dependency report on the unused event.